# How to call a function which takes parameter of type Map in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know the execution in case of Map.

```
void main(){
  var info = userInfo(); /* what can I pass here as args? */
  print(info);
}

userInfo(Map user){
  /* what do I write here? */
}
```

Comment: It would be the same as any other data type. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to achieve? Add more explanation!!

Comment: It is very good that you `want to know the execution in case of Map` Many other people don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

hi there you can pass a map and use the map as follow

```
  void main(){
     Map user_map= 
     {
    "first_name" : "fname",
    "last_name" : "lname",
    "gender" : "male",
    "location" : 
          { "state" : "state",
            "country" : "country",
            "place" : "place"
           } 
    }    
        
    var info = userInfo(user_map); /* what can I pass here as args? */
    print(info);
    }
            
            userInfo(Map user){
              /* here you can use the map values like if you want to print the value of key 
              first_name */
             print(user["first_name"]);
    
            }
```

Comment: Thank you! @Azad Prajapat, that exactly I want to know.